# MonoTouch binding protocol to different objective-c type name,

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios

Using the `BaseType` attribute, I can use the `Name` property to change the name of the actual objective-c class to bind to. This can help keep naming conventions consistent. However, what about protocols using the `Model` attribute?. There is no `Name` property to set.

Answer (score 3):

Just use BaseType in this case too:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject), Name="MyOtherName")]
[Model]
public interface MyDelegate {
}
```